# Jmeter HTTP setPath - How do i set dynamic path in http sampler

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I am new to jmeter and i am stuck in a condition . I am running jmeter http sample using a csv file where i am using a pre-processor script in which doing the following-

1. setting http.method as per request like POST , GET , PUT ,PATCH
2. setting http.path as "/restpath"
3. setting request body.json

For Path i am using a "http.path" and passed the same in http sampler like ${http.path}. All above is working fine until i have dependent HTTP request like below use case -

Step 1 - Hit HTTP Request on path "/**restpath**" . After successful submission , i got a **serverId** in response and save the same in json extractor variable "serverID".

Step 2- Now i have to hit http request on path "**/rest/${serverID}**" . when i am trying to pass the same from csv file then the same is not replacing with captured variable in step 1 . Whatever i passed in csv file in http.path got passed and submit.

**Expectation -** 
In Sheet --> http.path == "/restpath/**${serverID}**"
In HTTP Request submission --> "/restpath/**4894rh89r**"

**Actual -**
In Sheet --> http.path == "/restpath/**${serverID}**"
In HTTP Request submission --> "/restpath/**${serverID}**"

```
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPArgument;

//test input parameters
def httpMethod = vars.get("http.method");

//change the http method as per the data sheet
sampler.setMethod(httpMethod);

//set the HTTP Path
//URL url = new URL(vars.get('http.path'));
//vars.put('http.path',url.getPath());

//set the HTTP request body
if(!vars.get("input.json").equals("")){
    def dataToBePosted = new CompoundVariable(new File(vars.get("jmeter.test.home") + vars.get("input.json")).text).execute();
    def arg= new HTTPArgument("", dataToBePosted, null, true);
    arg.setAlwaysEncoded(false);
    sampler.getArguments().addArgument(arg);

    //HTTP Body is set to
    log.info(dataToBePosted);
}
```

Tried couple of hit n trial using __V() functions but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change this line:

```
def dataToBePosted = new CompoundVariable(new File(vars.get("jmeter.test.home") + vars.get("input.json")).text).execute();
```

to this one:

```
def dataToBePosted = ((org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable)([new File(vars.get("jmeter.test.home") + vars.get("input.json")).text])).execute()
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [EvalFunction source](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2.1/src/functions/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/functions/EvalFunction.java)
- [CompoundVariable JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/engine/util/CompoundVariable.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks for looking on this. I got the solution simply using `${__eval(${http.path})}` function :)